# Double domain name in category URL-s

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess, phpmyadmin

My site runs on the latest version of WordPress. However, I have a problem with categories. Permalinks are set correctly and my category path looks like this: `example.com/category-name`. Links work fine, but the problem is, I can also access every category with a link like this: `example.com/example.com/?cat=6`, which contains no posts.

I feel like I've tried everything to fix it. "siteurl" and "home" fields in the database are set correctly (`https://example.com`), as well as permalinks. It's not plugin nor theme related - I checked everything.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you saying that in the text field that you can edit, you have the text "example.com/category-name" or you have "category-name" in the text box?

Comment: No. My category permalinks are set that way: example.com/category-name. I can access categories via the URL I mentioned as well as this one: example.com/example.com/?cat=CategoryID. The only difference between these two is that the latter doesn't contain any posts.

In the database, "siteurl" and "home" fields have correct sitle adress inside (https://example.com). Or you meant something else?

Comment: `example.com/example.com/?cat=6` - So, `example.com` is repeated in the URL-path? Do you have a subdirectory called `/example.com`? What about `example.com/?cat=6`?

Comment: Yes, example.com is repeated in the URL path. I don't have subdirectory like that. example.com/?cat=6 redirects to the proper URL (example.com/category).

Comment: So basically - don't repeat the URL in the path. It's not necessary. You'll see to the left of it that the URL is already provided for you.

Comment: I have to fix it because Google indexes it (some categories are indexed properly with proper URL-s, some not). Like is said, categories accessed through such URL-s are empty. So basically users coming from Google see no content. And no, I can't simply redirect it because it's impossible if domain name is repeated in the URL.

Comment: "I can't simply redirect it because it's impossible if domain name is repeated in the URL" - I've just seen your _updated_ comment after posting my answer. Why is this "impossible"? This would seem to be a viable "workaround".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "workaround" the issue with a redirect in `.htaccess`, although it's not clear why this double-domain-URL would be accessible in the first place.

So, we can redirect URLs of the form `example.com/example.com/?cat=6` to `example.com/?cat=6`, which you then say is correctly redirected to `example.com/category` by WordPress.

For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:www\.)?example\.com/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This basically removes `example.com` (or `www.example.com`) from the start of the URL-path. Any query string that was present on the initial request (eg. `cat=6`) is passed through to the target URL by default.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Well, it actually works... Thank you so much! Just to make sure: If I don't use WWW, the code should look like this, right? RewriteRule ^(?:\.)?example\.com/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: If you don't use WWW then you don't need to change anything since the `www.` subdomain is made entirely optional in the regex. If you want to remove it then remove it entirely in the regex, ie. `^example\.com/(.*)`. Your suggestion would still "work", but doesn't make sense unless you are getting requests of the form `/.example.com/<something>` (note the dot after the first slash).

Comment: Thank you so much!